# Make links in response relative to new path

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

How do I redirect all my `hrefs` within my response to hit my new path. For e.g., my ingress file is

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-odin
  annotations:    
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1

spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /odin/?(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: flask-app-tutorial
          servicePort: 8080
```

When I visit the page at https://mysite/odin. It works and returns back the response:

The HTML response is:

```
<html>
..
    <body>
        <div>
            <a href="/v0/index">Home</a>
            <a href="/v0/login">Login</a>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

However, as you can see, the relative links are like `<a href="/v0/index">Home</a>`. If I click on that, it won't work since there is no link like `http://mysite/v0/index`. If I click on the link, I want it to go to `http://mysite/odin/v0/index`. Is it possible either by modifying the links in the response to have `odin` or if I do click on it, it looks at the source url i.e. `http://mysite/odin` and direct it relative to that?

```
Nginx Version: 1.15.10
ingress-nginx: 0.24.0
```

So far,I have tried the following.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding ""; #disable compression
  sub_filter '<head>' '<head> <base href="/odin/">';


nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: ":true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /odin

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
```

I have also tried [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/pull/3174#issuecomment-483315744) i.e.

```
 change the spec.rules.host.paths.path from /odin/?(.*) to/(odin/.*)
```

There may be a typo in the advice above. I think it should `http` instead of `host`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you fix the the `sub_filter` configuration snippet by including `sub_filter_once on;` as suggested in the other answer it will not work, because the `base` tag works only with relative paths (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base).

The `app-root` solution is technically correct, but boils down to the same thing as `<base href=... />`, and thus also will fail for `href` tags with a leading slash.

I can see two possibilities:

1) You can fix all your `href` tags, removing leading slashes. If you do that both solutions should work.

2) You can try to change your location rule to `- path: /(odin)?/?(.*)` and the rewrite annotation to: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2`(not forgetting to include the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"` annotation as well) and it will work with a leading slash as well.

It looks fragile though, as the rule will now match (almost) anything and you loose the possibility to fan out with NGINX with different path prefixes.

A modification of "2)" to make it a more viable alternative would be to match the `/v0` prefix if it's consistent among `href` tags, instead of basically anything.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem and inspired by your question I found a solution which worked for me.
Your annotation should work like this:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  sub_filter_once on;
  sub_filter '<base href="/"' '<base href="/odin/"';
```

As you see sub_filter is now enabled and I used *base* instead of *head*.

Comment: This will still not work due to absolute hrefs in OP's HTML.

Comment: It's noticeable that the `http_sub_module` only works when no compression is used between the ingress and the backend service! I have described this more in detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68246312/3276634