# Is there a best practice to implement ingress rule with rewrite to root

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

For example, I have a rule (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /something(/|$)(.*)
```

So anything that goes to `rewrite.bar.com/something` will go to `http-svc/`. And if `http-svc` will answer another location, e.g. `/static` there will be redirect to `rewrite.bar.com/static` and here we go - 404. I wonder is there any simple and clear solution to fix such situations without asking the developer to implement proxy_path variable or something like that?

Tried [Make links in response relative to new path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55718282/make-links-in-response-relative-to-new-path)

Answer (score 2):

Change the rewrite annotation to $1. Note I have also changed the path regex. That should do it.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /something/(.*)
```

Comment: Could you please explain the solution. In my understanding, there is nothing changed. `rewrite.bar.com/something/` -> `http-svc/`, `rewrite.bar.com/something/location` -> `http-svc/location` - this is fine, but if `http-svc` will answer with different relative url (e.g. `static/`), then browser will try to reach `rewrite.bar.com/static/` -> `404`. Am I wrong?

Comment: Kubernetes services are simply IP tables so don't take them as actual proxies. They will pass whatever you send them. The configuration is at the Ingress and the deployment's backend. So my solution just redirects `rewrite.bar.com/something/location` -> `http-svc/location` -> `http-backend/location`