# NGINX controller - remove filepath ONLY INSIDE service, then append it back

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to configure my NGINX for a specific scenario but I just can't manage to get it work. I'd really appreciate some help as I'm quite new to NGINX config stuff.

So here is the deal:
I have 3 services behind and ingress controller on kubernetes.

```
service1: HTTP://example.com/service1
service2: HTTP://example.com/service2
service3: HTTP://example.com/service3
```

When client requests something from HTTP://example.com/service3/products/categories, and the URL gets forwarded to the k8s ClusterIP service that is behind this URL, /service3 should be removed from the URL. So the service only gets HTTP://example.com/products/categories. **BUT, here is the thing that I can't seem to get to work. If the service redirects user to for example /nothing, user should be redirected to HTTP://example.com/service3/nothing (notice that /service3 has returned).**

Sidenote: I'm willing to switch to traefik if required.

Here is the k8s config for my ingress controller:

```
spec:
  ingressClassName: public
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port:
              number: 15003
        path: /service1
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: service2
            port:
              number: 15002
        path: /service2
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: service3
            port:
              number: 15004
        path: /service3
        pathType: Prefix
```

Comment: You are looking for rewrite annotation: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/. If you are using official ingress from nginx.org then here is guide https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/v1.11.3/examples/rewrites

Comment: @Howaboutnope Hey, thanks for the comment! I did try it, and it does indeed rewrite URL, but if I redirect from the service or use any assets, it doesn't work. Because then the /service1 gets stripped out on the client side too. Example: HTTP://example.com/service1/logo.png gets replaced with HTTP://example.com/logo.png (not found)

Comment: It's rather app problem then, you can try to use `sub_filter` or search for "server base path" setting in your services (a lot of apps has it). Also, check this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55718282/make-links-in-response-relative-to-new-path